# Facebook API - get list of user groups

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing a website which users can log in and share their link on facebook groups which joined by them, but I don't know how to retrieve the list of groups which joined by the user. Anyone, please assist me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It´s not possible anymore, the required permission for it has been removed and you can only get a list of groups you manage with the `user_managed_groups` permission. See the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) for more information.